# How to change this page counter to a unique page counter

Tags: php

I'm wanting to change this page counter into a unique page counter, I'm not that good a php and need some help.

counter.php file:

```
<?php 
$datei = fopen("countlog.txt","r");
$count = fgets($datei,1000);
fclose($datei);
$count=$count + 1 ;
echo "$count";
echo " hits";
echo "\n";

$datei = fopen("countlog.txt","w");
fwrite($datei, $count);
fclose($datei);
```

countlog.txt file contains the number of page views and i link counter.php in index.php

Thanks in advance

Comment: In what way do you want it to be a "unique page counter"?  Please explain what you mean by unique.